# edit parent and children in same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How would I edit a parent and collection of child objects in the same view? Any good tutorials on how to do this with mvc3 and automatic binding?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The key would be to use the following syntax in your view for your child collection items:

```
data.Children.Index and data.Children[index].Properties
```

Here is a simple example:

Model:

```
public class Parent
{
  public int FieldA { get; set; }
  public string FieldB { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParentChildViewModel
{
  public Parent Master { get; set; }
  public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  return View(new ParentChildViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ParentChildViewModel data)
{
  // Save your objects
}
```

View:

```
@model ParentChildViewModel
...
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Master.FieldA);

  @{ int index = 0; }
  @foreach(var c in Model.Children)
  {
    @Html.Hidden("data.Children.Index", index);
    @Html.TextBox("data.Children[" + index + "].Name")
    @{ index++; }
  }
}
```

On your controller you will receive on the .Children properties the changes made to the Name properties and on the .Master the changes made to the parent. The only trick is the **data.Children** syntax where data is the name of the variable name on you Controller. The data.Children.Index is required for each child and of course you have to increment the index.

Hope that help.